# Pressing function keys with pynput using variables from .txt file

Tags: python, keyboard, pynput

I am using pynput to log keyboard inputs to a .text file and trying to recreate them, but I'm having some trouble. A simple form of my code is as follows:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()

log_data = open('key_log_prob.txt', 'r')
key, keyclass, press = zip(*[x.split(';') for x in log_data.readlines()])

for i in key:
    keyboard.press(i)
    keyboard.release(i)
```

Where the .txt file looks like:

```
'b';KeyCode;1
'b';KeyCode;0
Key.f9;Key;1
Key.f9;Key;0
```

First of all, the data is imported as:

```
("'b'", "'b'", 'Key.f9', 'Key.f9')
```

Which is the incorrect format for keyboard.press().
I can use a workaround for the 'b' key by returning it to its original string form. This is a valid input for keyboard.press(). However, the 'Key.f9' is more complicated, because keyboard.press() requires an input of the format 'Key' and not 'string'.

I have not been able to find a way to import the data correctly from the .text or convert 'Key.f9' to a valid format.

For clarity, here is an example of how the code would work normally:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()

key = ['b', Key.f9]
for i in key:
    keyboard.press(i)
    keyboard.release(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently ran into the same problem and came here for a solution to no avail.
But perhaps you could try using a dictionary with the buttons and keys. I understand that this would be tedious to do but at least it would be usable.

```
from pynput import mouse

buttonDictionary = {'button.right':mouse.Button.right, 'button.left':mouse.Button.left}

button_string = 'button.left'

button = buttonDictionary[button_string]

mouse.Controller().click(button)
```

This is obviously an oversimplified version but it works.
Hopefully someone can find a better solution in future.

Edit:
I made the dictionary here:
https://github.com/DylanKirbs/pynputDictionary

Comment: Thanks for the dictionary! That solution popped into my head long after I asked this question, but I had already abandoned the project.
For future projects, I'll be sure to revisit your dictionary.